# Facebook permissions to know if a friend uses the same app

Tags: ios, facebook, permissions

I can successfully grab a list of friends with this NSURL, using the permissions "publish_stream":

```
NSURL *friendsList = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends
```

However, when I try the same thing with an added field, as in this URL:

```
NSURL *friendsList = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=installed"];
```

I get an error:

```
error =     {
        code = 2500;
        message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
```

So my question is what permissions should I be asking for to make the second URL work?

Bonus question: What URL param do I include to get a small profile pic come back in the same JSON object?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), you it **Requires app access_token**. However, playing with Graph API Explorer, I could get this info without this permission.

You can take a look at [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2C%20installed%2Cpicture) to test.

Also, the query on the above link returns the `picture` field, which will have an URL with the user picture.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I am still not understanding.  When I follow your link above, the installed field is grayed out with hover text indicating it is empty or not allowed by the access token. Playing around with the access token dialogs, I cannot find a combination that allows it :(

Comment: Now that I think bout it, it kinda makes sense that the graph explorer wouldn't be able to show anything for installed. Since there is no app id being passed to it. However, selecting the publish_stream, email and read_stream permissions predictable works within the graph explorer. Why doesn't it work in code? This is perplexing.